# Having Trouble Properly Ordering A List

Tags: sql

```
SELECT CaptainID, MONTH(TripStart) AS TripMonth,COUNT(LaunchID) AS TripCnt
FROM slTrip
GROUP BY CaptainID, TripStart, LaunchID
ORDER BY CaptainID, TripMonth, TripCnt ASC
```

I need three columns in which CaptainID is listed, TripMonth is obtained by using the MONTH() function on TripStart, and where TripCnt should be counting the number of trips each CaptainID has made in a specific month.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: When you edit to include the tag, you should also explain what is wrong with the SQL you've posted. *Having trouble* is useless unless you explain what *trouble* you're experiencing.

Comment: Remove LaunchID from GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend this:

```
SELECT CaptainID, MONTH(TripStart) AS TripMonth, COUNT(LaunchID) AS TripCnt
FROM slTrip
GROUP BY CaptainID,  MONTH(TripStart)
ORDER BY CaptainID, TripMonth, TripCnt ASC;
```

The `GROUP BY` should include only the non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  Many databases do not allow column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  They do permit them for the `ORDER BY`.